# Using debug is not stopping on breakpoints in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to debug a stored procedure using Oracle SQL Developer. The DB is on another box. I have granted privileges using

```
GRANT debug any procedure, debug connect session TO <user>;
```

I have placed the break point inside the procedure on one of the assignment lines. I have tried other places too out of desperation. When I click debug I get the debug dialog and I fill in all the values. When I hit debug the stored procedure runs, the debug controls flash across the screen in a second and then it finishes and exits. It misses all the breakpoints as if it weren't even there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found the answer by accident. Turns out after I altered the proc slightly (added debugs) and the saved then it started working.

Comment: This answer will probably not help others in your situation much, I think when you changed something and saved -> saving a Stored Procedure in SQL-Developer actually compiles it in the Database -> See my answer

Answer (score 14):

For debugging to work you have to compile the Package / Procedure with the Debug-Flag. In SQL-Developer this is done by opening the package and clicking on the little "Gears with a bug"-Button (Compile Package for Debug)

After that all your breakpoints will work.

Comment: Correct cause for my case